# public sharing of amazon ami webserver without allowing code access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to share a public ami that will not work except with a given public key. This ami is supposed to run a web application on launching using cloud-init.
The problem is that I want to secure the code inside this ami and not allowing any user to access it. On running the image, cloud init can remove existing public key and replace it with some other key to prevent ssh but that doesn't prevent anyone from taking a snapshot of the ami and try to access it from any other amazon instance. There is no direct method provided by amazon to solve the problem. I hope anyone expert in the field to give me a work around to solve this problem.

Comment: There is simply no technological solution to this.  Your code running on my instance means I can access your code... period, paragraph, end of file.  The correct universally-applicable answer is that this is a problem you solve with a software license.  However, there may be a workaround for your *specific* use case, similar to one that I use -- I have a product I host for a client in a VPC that I own but create exclusively for their copy, and allow them access my running service that I deployed for their use, via VPC peering.  What does your product do (generally)?

Comment: It is webapp based on python flask however it calls compiled binaries that I don't want them to be reverse engineered...The idea is that I don't want to run this service and paying for the costs...I just want the user to run the ami, pay for its cost without accessing the ami....
this would be possible if amazon allows encrypted public amis or amis with limited access

Comment: Yes, but they don't.  You are required by the Marketplace guidelines to allow your customer to have SSH access to their instance.